# Проверка нажатия кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть цикл foreach, в теле которого происходит поиск объектов:

```
foreach(string o int obj) 
{
   //часть кода
   Button but = new Button(); // таким образом я создаю кнопку
   but.Click += button2_Click; //при нажатии на кнопку выполняется button2_Click
}
```

Далее я получаю имя этого объекта и записываю в стринговую переменную. В методе `button2_Click()` я вызываю метод с параметром из другого файла.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TaskEditor tK = new TaskEditor();
    tK.taskread(name); 
}
```

Как мне передать из цикла имя объекта в метод *taskread*, который в методе *button2Click*?

Если делать так, как у меня, то передается имя только последнего объекта

Comment: А почему вы не пользуетесь XAML'ом? Есть какая-то специальная причина, что вы создаёте объекты в коде?

Comment: Используйте `sender.name`, или какое есть поле у `sender` для имени.

Comment: В комментарии к ответу VladD вы написали, что таким образом находите все файлы в папке. Вы не могли бы привести более полный текст задачи и более полный пример кода? Тогда, возможно, её вам помогут решить без code behind.

Comment: Я создаю их через код, потому что нужна кнопка к каждому найденному объекту, чье количество не всегда известно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть же свойство для этого в контролах:

```
foreach(var str in obj) 
{
    //...
    var buttonName = "";
    var button = new Button();
    button.Tag = buttonName;
    button.Click += button2_Click;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     var button = (Button)sender;
     var name = (string)button.Tag;
     TaskEditor tK = new TaskEditor();
     tK.taskread(name); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы *можете* сделать так:

```
foreach (string o in obj) 
{
    // ни в коем случае не выносите переменную buttonName за цикл
    string buttonName = ...;
    Button but = new Button();
    but.Click += (sender, args) => button2_Click(buttonName);
}

private void button2_Click(string buttonName)
{
    TaskEditor tK = new TaskEditor();
    tK.taskread(buttonName);
}
```

Но судя по всему, вы делаете что-то неправильно, обычно такие изыски в WPF не нужны.

Comment: Вообще у меня немного костыльный метод
Я таким образом нахожу все файлы в папке

Comment: @andrew: Ого! Так, интересно. Тогда расскажите, что именно вы делаете, наверняка можно всё сделать намного легче.

Comment: грубо говоря - блокнот с парой фич

Comment: Окей, это наверное слишком общий ответ. Судя по всему, у вас есть список объектов, и вы хотите их отобразить? Для этого обычно используется не создание контролов вручную, как в WinForms, а `ListView` (или `TreeView`, если у вас древовидная структура).